# Simulate guitar chords on lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to simulate guitar strumming by defining chords like this :

```
Downstroke:
\fixed c {
  <dis, ais, dis g ais>4
}

Upstroke:
\fixed c {
  <ais' g' dis ais, dis,>4
}
```

This is the D# Major barre chord.

This kinda works. For this I have to first find what notes make up the guitar chord. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this ?

Edit:
To clarify: I want to produce strumming like effect in the MIDI output.

Comment: Back in the mid/late 90s I used to have a device you wore like a belt with a box at the front containing 6 solid metal 'strings'. Using a keyboard to define your chord, this 'strummer' would remap to guitar chords & you could record the result as Midi. It was brilliant when we were making thousands of sound-alike Midi files for sale. I thought I'd never remember what it was called, but I actually managed to find one for sale on eBay, complete with pictures. The Charlie Lab Digitar. Charlie Lab Digitar - https://www.ebay.com/itm/175553530502

Comment: Pic for when the link vanishes - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGgKb.jpg & a review of it from back in the day - https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/charlie-lab-digitar

Answer (score 3):

#### Warning: this ain’t pretty.

But let’s break it down:

<sub>(These are mocked examples; obviously when I compiled them, there were durations that are absent in the code, among other details.)</sub>

##### E minor, as a chord

```
<e, b, e g b e'>
```

[image: E minor as a chord]

##### E minor, as strummed

```
\grace {
  e, ~ b, ~ e ~ g ~ b ~ e' ~
}
```

[image: E minor, as strummed]

##### Add `\tieWaitForNote`

```
\set tieWaitForNote = ##t
\grace {
  e, ~ b, ~ e ~ g ~ b ~ e' ~
}
<e, b, e g b e'>
\unset tieWaitForNote
```

[image: Simulated strum in LilyPond]

Then, to control how “fast” the strumming is and how long the chord lasts:

##### Add durations

```
\set tieWaitForNote = ##t
\grace {
  e,16 ~ b, ~ e ~ g ~ b ~ e' ~
}
<e, b, e g b e'>4
\unset tieWaitForNote
```

Finally, define that in a variable for reuse:

##### Define it as a variable

```
em_down = {
  \set tieWaitForNote = ##t
  \grace {
    e,16 ~ b, ~ e ~ g ~ b ~ e' ~
  }
  <e, b, e g b e'>4
  \unset tieWaitForNote
}
guitar_strumming = {
  \em_down
  \em_down
  \em_down
  \em_down
}
\score {
  \new Staff \guitar_strumming
  \midi {}
}
```

Put the notes in reverse order for strumming up. Repeat for any other chord combination you wish.

You can finagle with it to make a function, such as can dynamically control, at least, the duration (e.g., `\em_down 16 4`), but for a first start, this can do what you’re requesting.

This seems to me to be pretty clunky, but it’s a self-taught effort that got what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: This may work for me. But I am having hard time understading how it works. Could you explain a bit more? Is there a way  to hide this in the PDF, but still have it in the MIDI ?

Comment: I added pictures which hopefully demonstrate it better. As far as allowing in MIDI while hiding in PDF, I know of 2 options: 1. make two `\score` expressions, one that only has `\layout {}` in it and the other `\midi {}` and put the code you want to show in the former and the code you want to hear in the latter; 2. make one `\score` expression, but apply the necessary overrides to whatever context the strummed music lives in to hide strum parts.

Comment: You can use tags (inside the variable) to get a different MIDI & PDF results:  https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/different-editions-from-one-source#using-tags

Comment: Yes, using tags is another method, although I think that still would require one `\score` for PDF and another `\score` for MIDI if they differ, right?

Comment: @Neal Yes it would.